# Count all the active products inside a category; Left Join not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

my schema is designed to handle product sizes, so products belong to an item, and an item with a certain size is a product.

I need to select all the categories and count the active products inside them (Products.IsHidden = false).

Here is my schema;

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES (
  CategoryId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE ITEMS (
  ItemId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CategoryId int NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(255),
  Description varchar(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId) REFERENCES CATEGORIES(CategoryId)
);

CREATE TABLE SIZES (
  SizeId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS (
  ProductId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ItemId int NOT NULL,
  SizeId int NOT NULL,
  Price float,
  Weight float,
  Stock int NOT NULL,
  Discount float NULL,
  CreatedAt DateTime,
  PictureLoc varchar(255),
  IsHidden boolean,
  FOREIGN KEY (SizeId) REFERENCES SIZES(SizeId),
  FOREIGN KEY (ItemId) REFERENCES ITEMS(ItemId)
);
```

Here is my code (my aim is to count all the active products inside a category);
Assuming I have 2 active Products (IsHidden=false) in Category A.

```
SELECT 
  CATEGORIES.CategoryId, 
  CATEGORIES.Name, 
  Count(PRODUCTS.ProductId) as ActiveProducts 
FROM CATEGORIES 
  LEFT JOIN ITEMS 
   ON CATEGORIES.CategoryId = ITEMS.CategoryId 
  LEFT JOIN PRODUCTS 
   ON ITEMS.ItemId = PRODUCTS.ItemId 
WHERE PRODUCTS.IsHidden = FALSE 
GROUP BY CATEGORIES.CategoryId
```

***but this code returns only 1 row.***

```
CategoryId | Category Name | ActiveProducts
1          | A             | 2
```

Shouldn't the other categories with 0 product count show up in the results? ***My expected result is:***

```
CategoryId | Category Name | ActiveProducts
1          | A             | 2
2          | B             | 0
3          | C             | 0
```

How do I come up with my expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions on the second table in a `left join` belong in the `on` clause, not the `where` clause:

```
SELECT c.CategoryId, c.Name, Count(p.ProductId) as ActiveProducts
FROM CATEGORIES c LEFT JOIN
     ITEMS i
     ON c.CategoryId = i.CategoryId LEFT JOIN
     PRODUCTS p
     ON i.ItemId = p.ItemId AND p.IsHidden = FALSE
GROUP BY c.CategoryId;
```